# Using Pandas to Rename Files - Truth of the Value Error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-os

I am trying to write a program that allows me rename files with an excel spreadsheet and I keep getting to the same error message. I really appreciate any help. The error is:

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Here is my current code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

os.chdir('C:\\Users\\sferrier\\Desktop\\Test 1')
xl = pd.read_excel('rename_test.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame(xl, columns=["Orginal File Name","New File Name"])

for file in os.listdir():
    if file == df["Orginal File Name"]:
        os.rename(file, df["New File Name"])
    else:
        print(file + "was not renamed")
```

Answer (score 1):

try this after constructing `df`:

```
for x in df.values.tolist():
    os.rename(x[0], x[1])
```

or if you like explicit variable names:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    os.rename(row["Orginal File Name"], row["New File Name"])
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this block

```
for file in os.listdir():
    if file == df["Orginal File Name"]:
        os.rename(file, df["New File Name"])
    else:
        print(file + "was not renamed")
```

Specifically, in this line-

```
if file == df["Orginal File Name"]:
```

The problem with this line is that the variable `file` is a single string whereas `df["Orginal File Name"]` is an entire column. So essentially, you are trying to compare a single string with an array containing a whole bunch of strings.

To correct this, you can iterate over the rows, like so

```
for file in os.listdir():
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        os.rename(row["Orginal File Name"], row["New File Name"])
```

**EDIT**

The `FileNotFoundError` that OP is getting is probably because there's a filename in your dataframe that is not actually present in the directory. You can run the following block

```
for file in os.listdir():
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        try:
            os.rename(row["Orginal File Name"], row["New File Name"])
        except:
            print(row["Orginal File Name"])
```

This block will allow you to continue further ahead even if the file is not present in your directory and will print out the name of the files that are not present.

Comment: Thank you so much. This works.  It does end with an FileNotFoundError, is bad programming to just pass the error?

Comment: Thank you again, that works without ending in an error. Next time I will use the Try and Except when my code ends with an error.